# Create or update websites task failed

Tags: azure-pipelines, cicd, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

Devops release fails with the error: "Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'X' does not exist."

```
- task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0              
              inputs:
                EnableIIS: true
                WebsiteName: 
                WebsitePhysicalPath: 'X:\iis\abc.com'
                WebsitePhysicalPathAuth: WebsiteWindowsAuth
                WebsiteAuthUserName: 
                WebsiteAuthUserPassword: 
                AddBinding: true
                Bindings: '{"bindings":[{"protocol":"https","ipAddress":"All Unassigned","port":"443","hostname":"","sslThumbprint":"","sniFlag":true}]}'
                CreateOrUpdateAppPoolForWebsite: true
                ConfigureAuthenticationForWebsite: true
                AppPoolNameForWebsite: 
                AnonymousAuthenticationForWebsite: true
                WindowsAuthenticationForWebsite: false
```

The server it is trying to access has the location available but still I see this error.

Comment: Check and ensure the drive '**X**' is indeed existing on the Windows agent machine. Use the user authentication provide on the task to login to the Windows agent machine, ensure the user has the access to the drive '**X**' and contents under it. You also can try to use the admin user authentication to see if it can work.

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT Thank you for responding. The issue was with : next to the drive label it should be $ sign and that works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with : next to the drive label it should be $ sign and that works fine

Modify the below value and it will work as expected

```
WebsitePhysicalPath: 'X$\iis\abc.com'
```

Comment: Glad that the issue can be fixed, and thank you for sharing the answer. Maybe, you can accept yourself answer as the solution of this case. this could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues.